# tensorflow dataset iterator API throws random memory error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow, and I have a dummy script for utilizing the dataset API. Nevertheless, this script will randomly throw me off by the error

```
InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__StridedSlice_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Expected begin, end, and strides to be 1D equal size tensors, but got shapes [1,128], [1], and [1] instead. [Op:StridedSlice] name: strided_slice/
```

the weird thing is, I put debug point `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in the tensorflow python code, I found the issue comes from this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py?#L1138). I added this snipped for debugging, and the debugging variable is telling me, `packed_begin` and its exact copy `__packed_begin` somehow becomes a 128 length vector, whereas `begin` and my `_packed_begin` remains a single number.

```
      # added snipped for debugging
      _begin = tf.identity(begin)
      _packed_begin = array_ops_stack.stack(begin)
      __packed_begin = tf.identity(packed_begin)
      __packed_end = tf.identity(packed_end)
```

below is my dummy scripts. what is the thing I am doing wrong? thanks

```
#file preparation
#!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
#!pip3 install --user -r models/official/requirements.txt
#!pip3 install tensorflow-text-nightly
#!pip install tensorflow_text


import hashlib
import sys

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

sys.path.append("models")
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_text

# from official.nlp.bert import tokenization
from official.nlp import optimization
from official.nlp.data import classifier_data_lib
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://archive.org/download/fine-tune-bert-tensorflow-train.csv/train.csv.zip",
    dtype={
        "qid": str,
        "question_text": str,
        "target": np.int32,
    },
)

df_train, _df_r = train_test_split(
    df, train_size=0.0075, random_state=42, stratify=df["target"]
)


train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (df_train["question_text"], df_train["target"])
)

preprocessor = hub.KerasLayer(
    "https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_preprocess/3"
)


def to_feature(text, label):
    def helper(txt, labl):
        t = preprocessor([txt])
        print(txt)
        print(f"here? {[(k, v.shape) for k, v in t.items()]}")
        
        x = [v[0] for k, v in t.items()]
        return x + [labl]

    input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_id = tf.py_function(
        helper,
        inp=[text, label],
        Tout=[
            tf.int32,
            tf.int32,
            tf.int32,
            tf.int32,
        ],
    )
    input_ids.set_shape([128])
    input_mask.set_shape([128])
    segment_ids.set_shape([128])
    label_id.set_shape([])
    return {
        "input_word_ids": input_ids,
        "input_mask": input_mask,
        "input_type_ids": segment_ids,
    }, label_id


def build_model2():
    return tf.keras.Model()

model = build_model2()
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy()],
)

from keras.src.engine import data_adapter

data_handler = data_adapter.DataHandler(x=train_ds, model=model)

for epoch, iterator in data_handler.enumerate_epochs():
    for _ in range(10000):
        print(next(iterator))
```